# configuring twiki

Tags: twiki

i am configuring twiki.

when i give my user id and password it does proceed, but when i hit the cancel button it takes me to the new registration page and when i make a new id on that page it gives another error of access denied.

here is my error message

```
Access check on Main.WebHome failed. Action "redirect": unsafe redirect to http://192.168.15.24/twiki/bin/oops/Main/TWikiRegistration?twiki_redirect_cache=284eea1940e2adc7f9ed6bdc45456713: host does not match {DefaultUrlHost} , and is not in {PermittedRedirectHostUrls}"http://localhost".
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is in the configuration. Find out your ip-adress and open the link http:///twiki/bin/configure. in the section "General Path settings" there is an entry named {DefaultUrlHost}. Set it to http://

BR
Frank

Answer (score 0):

There is a file named `LocalSite.cfg` inside `/www/twiki` directory. Go to this line and change it to your respective twiki URL:

```
$TWiki::cfg{DefaultUrlHost} and $TWiki::cfg{PermittedRedirectHostUrls} path
```